# dynamically set width of column headers based on text inside it

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am building a table as show below[image]

The width of the columns is constant now. [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/SSV0811/r2n3dxnt/) is the link to my code.
We can see that second column occupies more space than it requires.

My question is can we control the width of the column based on its content, while maintaining the current setup of the table where table headers are slanted.

```css
    * {
      box-sixing: border-box;
    }
    
    .outerDiv {
   //   background: grey;
      height: 200px;
      width: 100px;
      border: 1px solid black;
      border-bottom: 0;
      border-left: 0;
      transform: skew(-30deg) translateX(58%);
    }
    
    th:first-child .outerDiv {
      border-left: 1px solid black;
      position: relative;
    }
    
    .innerDiv {
      position: absolute;
      width: 220px;
      height: 85px;
      bottom: -34%;
      left: 10px;
      transform: skew(30deg) rotate(-60deg);
      transform-origin: 0 0;
      text-align: left;
    }
    
    body,
    html {
      height: 100%;
    }
    
    body {
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
    }
    
    table {
      border-collapse: collapse;
    }
    
    td {
      border: 1px solid black;
    }
```

```html
    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
      <tr> 
              <th>
          <div class="outerDiv">
            <div class="innerDiv"></div>
          </div>
        </th>
        <th>
          <div class="outerDiv">
            <div class="innerDiv">First column header cell is very long  </div>
          </div>
        </th>
        <th>
          <div class="outerDiv">
            <div class="innerDiv">Second column</div>
          </div>
        </th>
        <th>
          <div class="outerDiv">
            <div class="innerDiv">Third column header cell is very very very very long</div>
          </div>
        </th> 
      </tr>
   <tr>
      <td class="wider">Target</td>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>26</td>
      <td>9</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="wider">75th Percentile</td>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>26</td>
      <td>9</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="wider">50th Percentile</td>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>26</td>
      <td>9</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="wider">25th Percentile</td>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>26</td>
      <td>9</td>
    </tr>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `display: grid` and use `grid-auto-columns` or `grid-auto-rows` with `min-content` value:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-auto-columns